# Из-за чего в нижеприведенном коде возникает ArgumentException с сообщением "Поток был недоступен для чтения"?

Tags: c#

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string name_f1 = "input.txt";
        string name_f2 = "otput.txt";

        FileStream inp_f = new FileStream(name_f1, FileMode.Create);

        StreamWriter write_f1 = new StreamWriter(inp_f);
        Console.WriteLine("Введите входные данные: ");
        string inp_data = Console.ReadLine();
        write_f1.Write(inp_data);
        write_f1.Close();

        FileStream out_f = new FileStream(name_f2, FileMode.Create);
        try
        {
            StreamReader reader_f = new StreamReader(inp_f);
            string content_f = reader_f.ReadToEnd();
            StreamWriter write_f2 = new StreamWriter(out_f);
            write_f2.Write(content_f);
            reader_f.Close();
            write_f2.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

В приведенном выше коде происходит ArgumentException с сообщением "Поток был недоступен для чтения". Сначала я подумал, что я рано закрываю поток или его вообще не надо закрывать, но ни то ни другое не помогло. Как мне кажется, ошибка происходит в следующем участке кода:

```
FileStream out_f = new FileStream(name_f2, FileMode.Create);
try
{
    StreamReader reader_f = new StreamReader(inp_f);
    string content_f = reader_f.ReadToEnd();
    StreamWriter write_f2 = new StreamWriter(out_f);
    write_f2.Write(content_f);
    reader_f.Close();
    write_f2.Close();
}
```

Comment: "Извините, партайгеноссе, мне надо перемотать касету." Штирлиц

Comment: `inp_f.Position = 0;`

Comment: Автор, Вы ведь уже задавали этот вопрос, Вам указали на ошибки, может быть стоило поправить его, а не создавать новый? Здесь ведь не СМС-конкурс, принцип "чем больше отправишь -- тем лучше" не работает.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему поток недоступен для чтения?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/738544/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Comment: @lgor inp_f.Position = 0;     это на какой троке?

Comment: @GeVaMain, Вам намекают, что у Вас как раз нет этой строки.

Comment: @SerafimProzorov если я вставлю это то тогда будет ошибка "Доступ к закрытому файлу невозможен."

Comment: @GeVaMain Естественно будет. Когда Вы закрываете StreamWriter, вместе с ним закрывается и поток inp_f. И еще вопрос к Вам: в чем смысл писать сначала в один файл, а потом переписывать в другой? Интересуюсь с целью указать Вам на ошибки и привести верное решение.

Comment: @SerafimProzorov Таково задание по С#. Пытаюсь понять как работать с файлами на С#

Comment: **Закрывающим:** этот вопрос является более полным, плюс на него уже дан ответ. Так что стоит не этот вопрос закрывать как дубликат, а наоборот, «Почему поток недоступен для чтения?» как дубликат этого.

Answer (score 4):

После записи в поток Вам необходимо переместить указатель на его начало, но в Вашем примере это не поможет, потому что когда Вы закрываете StreamReader, Вы закрываете и Stream, с которым он связан, то есть, Ваше предположение о несвоевременном закрытии потока в общем-то верно, однако, в Вашем коде достаточно много ошибок присущих новичку, поэтому позволю себе привести свой вариант кода:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        /* 
         * Переменные в C# принято именовать в camelCase, а не в under_score,
         * имена лучше давать осмысленные, например, intermediateFileName, но никак не name_f1),
         * кроме того, литеральные значения, которые не будут меняться лучше объявлять константами.
         */
        const string intermediateFileName = "input.txt";
        const string destinationFileName = "otput.txt";


        Console.WriteLine("введите строку: ");

        string input = Console.ReadLine();

        /*
         * Все операции, могущие вызвать исключение должны быть обернуты в try-catch.
         * Все манипуляции с Disposable-типами, такими, как Stream должны быть обернуты в блоки using или,
         * при невозможности, в try-catch-finally.
         */
        Stream intermediateStream = null;
        Stream destinationStream = null;

        try
        {
            intermediateStream = new FileStream(intermediateFileName, FileMode.Create);

            StreamWriter intermediateWriter = new StreamWriter(intermediateStream);

            intermediateWriter.Write(input);
            intermediateWriter.Flush();

            // Устанавливаем указатель на начало потока.
            intermediateStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            // Копировать из одного файла в другой лучше все же побайтово через буфер
            destinationStream = new FileStream(destinationFileName, FileMode.Create);

            // Количество байт, прочитанных при последнем чтении
            int lastCount = 0;
            // Буфер длиной 256 байт
            byte[] buffer = new byte[256];

            do
            {
                /*
                 * читаем из входного потока, записываем в выходной, если прочитано меньше, чем размер буфера,
                 * значит поток прочитан полностью
                 */
                lastCount = intermediateStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                destinationStream.Write(buffer, 0, lastCount);
            }
            while (lastCount == buffer.Length);
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Произошла ошибка [{x.Message}]:\r\n\r\n{x.StackTrace}");
        }
        finally
        {
            // Если стримы инициализированы, закрываем их.
            intermediateStream?.Close();
            destinationStream?.Close();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Нажмите любую клавишу");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```